# Airflow backfilled tasks stuck in queued state after clearing state

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

How do I clear the state of a backfilled run and get it to run again such that the execution time of that run is the past date.

- I backfilled a DAG that runs every 5 hours to have one day's worth of runs
- After all of the runs completed successfully, I cleared the state of one of the run i.e. the 1500hr run
- This moves the run to a Queued state (as expected) but the run never actually runs so it gets stuck in a queued state
- When I have runs which are scheduled normally i.e. not backfilled, clearing the state, queues and kicks off these runs almost instantly.
- If I backfill the runs using the CLI it runs all runs for that day all over again instead of only running the queued runs.